# Div Appearing over Heading

Tags: html, css

I'm very new to css and html.  I'm setting up a text version of the oregon trail, and on my main menu screen one of my divs is appearing over some text that I have fading in and out. I've searched quite a bit and couldn't get any of the solutions I found to solve it.

**CSS and HTML**

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

#title {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

div.menu {
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

p {
  position: relative;
  color: burlywood;
  text-align: center;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

h7 {
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  animation: fadeIn 2s linear infinite alternate;
}
```

```html
<div id="title">
  <h1>The Oregon Trail</h1>
  <h2>Main Menu</h2>
  <h7>Press Key to Select Option</h7>
</div>
<div class="menu">
  <p>1. Travel the Trail</p>
  <p>2. Learn about the Trail</p>
  <p>3. See the Oregon Top Ten</p>
  <p>4. Turn Sound Off</p>
</div>
```

Any tips as to why this is occurring?

Comment: Side note, there is no `<h7>` element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your `<h7>` styling in the CSS from `position: relative;`to `position: initial;`. That should fix the problems of it being overlapped!

Comment: that worked, I have one more question for ya, how would one go about getting the menu class to appear vertically in the center? or to get some more space between that and the h7 tag?

Comment: For the spacing, that's pretty easy, just put in some `<br>` tags between your two div tags. For the menu class appearing vertically, I'm not sure I understand what you mean? For me, it already shows centered and appears numbered vertically.

Comment: i just mean so it's centered in the page below h7, but from your advice `<br>` should work

Comment: Yes, `<br>` is the simple solution. You could also use CSS to move the margin on the `<div id="title">` to down however far you want. That would give you more control, and ultimately would probably be considered the "Proper" solution to fix that. However, for what you're going for, using `<br>` should work just fine! :)

Comment: Just use multiple `<br>` tags! Like this: `<br><br><br>`. You can use as many as you want or need to!

Answer (score 0):

This here is your issue:

```
h7 {
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;  
    animation: fadeIn 2s linear infinite alternate;
}
```

`top` will move the element, but elements around it will treat it as if it was not moved.  You'll probably want to use `margin-top` or `padding-top` to move it into the position you want instead of `top`.

Here is a link to an MDN page that explains it:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

> **Relative**
>   The element is positioned according to the normal flow of the document, and then offset relative to itself based on the values of top, right, bottom, and left. The offset does not affect the position of any other elements;